# flex-shrink and flex-basis properties doesn't work

Tags: css, flexbox

Hi I started working with flexbox recently and I can't understand a few things. First off, I can't make flex children to have a specific width. I have tried using width, flex-basis properties, none of which seemed to have any effect. Another thing is that the flex-shrink property doesn't work. Please help!!

```css
.flexbox {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.flexchild {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: 'Arial' sans-serif;
  flex: 1;
}

.flexchild:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.flexchild:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}

.flexchild:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexchild">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="flexchild">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proidentest.</div>
  <div class="flexchild">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
  <div class="flexchild">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working as intended, what is the issue? how do you want it to behave?

Comment: I wanted them to have a fixed width and didnt want them to shrink

Comment: you allowed them to grow by setting flex:1 ... so they won't shrink but will grow. If you want a fixed size you need to disable the shrink (not needed btw) and don't allow the grow (remove flex:1)